# Individual Email Results Issue (same JobID different BatchID)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, marketing-cloud-connect

we are having a problem with Individual email results.
Our aim is to show individual email results in Salesforce after sending emails from a journey configured in Marketing Cloud.
We sent several emails from Marketing Cloud to the same lead id using the same triggered send that has the template email 'A'.
We noticed that marketing cloud create the individual email result in Salesforce for this lead id.

After that we sent another email from the same journey to the same lead, we noticed that the IER has been updated in Salesforce overwriting the information related to the first send.

We verified in the Sent Data View (configured using a query) where marketing logs all information related to the email sends and we found out that email sends using the same triggered send and template 'A' show the same Job ID, but different Batch ID.

We found out that marketing usually assigns a JobID to a triggered send and this doesn't change until the template email linked to the triggered is changed by the user.

This behaviour involves that we lose every event (opens, clicks, bounces,etc.) related to the previous sends and the IER shows only events of the last send.

Have you ever seen this behaviour and found a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what your setup is in Salesforce.

But in the views, if you need tracking on the individual email level, the views are based on SubscriberID, JobID, BatchID, and ListID (this is not an ID for a listlist, but its another field in the view that happens to be called listID)

If you inner join or update your object in Salesforce based on these four keys, you should be able to get individual results. It might be overwriting the data already in the object because it is matching on just SubscriberID and BatchID (JobID will stay static as long as the triggered send/journey is actively running). It needs that extra ListID data point to differentiate!

Hope this helps!